# error message error when running

Tags: magento2, javascript

Why do I still get an error message when I run these js files at the correct path?[image]

Answer (score 0):

- Under the **theme** table in the Magento database, check the type of your theme. Change the type to **0**, if it is not.
- Check whether your theme has the correct **parent_id** associated. If not, update its value.
- Try to remove all empty folders under app/design/frontend directory.

After every step, don't forget to run the following commands:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento s:s:d -f 
php bin/magento cache:clean
```