# Why is a piece of code closed but still processed by Google?

Tags: magento2, javascript

When I close this code, why does it still load the code and cause an error when running?[image] [image]

Comment: This seems related to your previous question : https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/370431/45441  If you have more information about your issue, please edit your first question instead

Answer (score 0):

Delete your **generated** and **var** folder
using `rm -rf generated/*` and `rm -rf var/*` then run the below commands

```
Php bin/magento setup:upgrade;
php bin/magento s:d:c;
php bin/magento s:s:d -f;
php bin/magento c:f
```